# TypeScript namespace merging across files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm having some issues with getting a namespace across files to resolve and compile properly.  According to [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Declaration%20Merging.md#merging-namespaces) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787125/typescript-internal-modules-across-several-files), the following should produce no issue:

App.Core.ts

```
namespace App.Core {
    export function createElem(tagName: string): JQuery {
        return $(document.createElement(tagName));
    }
}
```

App.Core.SubModule.ts

```
/// <reference path="App.Core.ts" />
namespace App.Core.SubModule {
    export function Test(): JQuery {
        return App.Core.createElem("div");
}
```

However, Visual Studio is giving me an error on the function call in `App.Core.SubModule.Test` stating `Property 'createElem' does not exist on type 'typeof Core'`  My understanding is that if a namespace is across multiple files TS compiler will automatically resolve those namespaces. It looks like the corresponding JavaScript is coming out correct however the lack of intellisense (and the red squiggle error line) is exceptionally frustrating and making me second guess what I'm writing.

Is this an issue with my file setup, with TS compiler, or with Visual Studio 2015's apparently broken TypeScript intellisense functionalities right now?

Comment: This code compiles fine on Webstorm. I suspect that the ordering of the files in the combined output makes a difference. Have a look at it. Anyway, If you can, move away from namespaces and use external modules. This will save you a lot of these types of headaches

Comment: Followed your advice and used external modules instead. Typescript is still a very foreign idea to me. Took a little bit of searching and digging to realize that Typescript's output doesn't run in a browser without other resources like `require.js`.  Definitely had a hard time deciphering and finding that on the TS documentation. But thank you for the help! Finally can get moving on the next part of my project!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Visual Studio is giving me an error on the function call in App.Core.SubModule.Test stating Property 'createElem' does not exist on type 'typeof Core'

Suspect you have a root level `import` or `export` in either of the files. **That makes the file a module** and disconnects it from the global namespace.

## Quick Fix

Remove that import / export but be warned that it can lead to more problems https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/outfile

## Proper Fix

Don't use namespace. Just use modules : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/modules/external-modules

Comment: I converted to external modules which fixed the 1st issue! Now I'm trying to implement a TS file in an Area of my MVC app, and I want it to reference my App.Core.ts module. However I'm finding 2 issues: 1) the relative path becomes tedious to create (`require("../../../Scripts/TypeScript/App.Core")`), and 2) I'm trying to keep the TS and JS separate by placing them into Scripts/TypeScript and Scripts/JS respectively. The TS import needs to reference the TS folder to compile, but the JS output needs to reference the JS folder. Is it generally not advised to create a folder structure like this?

Comment: Hi @basarat. Why do you think, that "Proper fix" is not using namespaces at all? As far as I understand them, I think they are much better choice to use them in ASP.NET projects, where you have backend code writtent in C# and frontend in TypeScript. I think, that in this scenario, modules are overkill.

Comment: thank you! couldn't for the life of me figure out what was going wrong. Can you not make use of `import` at all in a file using a global namespace?

Comment: @basarat both links return 404, I would recommend add the relevant code here.

Answer (score 1):

### File A

```js
namespace A {
  export type User = {
    name: string,
    age: number
  }
}
```

### File B

```js
namespace A {
  export type Goods = {
    city: string,
    price: number
  }
}
```

### File C - merge namespaces here

```js
declare module 'Final' {
  import 'namespace-b';
  import 'namespace-a';
}
```

File index.ts

```js
import './namespace-final;';

function multipleNamespaces() {
  let user: A.User | A.Goods | undefined;
  user = { name: '', age: 0 }; // valid
  user = {city: 'beijing', price: 100} // vlaid
  user = 'test' // invalid
}
```